# Save over layed image to sdcard

Tags: android, image, save, overlay, sd-card

I want to save the frame layout in which I have set a background and another image is placed on its top.
When I use onclick button it gives me 'force close error'.

I am using the following code:

```
 FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File(root,"androidlife.jpg");
 Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainLayout.getWidth(), mainLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
 mainLayout.draw(c);
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
 try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if (fos != null) {
       b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
       fos.close();
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Here is the error-log:

```
05-03 00:39:37.281: W/dalvikvm(445): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at org.example.touch.Touch$1.onClick(Touch.java:60)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 00:39:37.301: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are doing this:

```
FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

And R.id.imageView is most likely a reference to a `ImageView`. You better do something like:

```
ImageView mainLayout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: i solved the problem myself.... it was wrong refernce....i change to

      FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

because i use FrameLayout for my xml files..so it cannot be change to **ImageView** ..anyways thanks to all